# Copy first section content to other existing sections

Tags: orbeon, xforms

Lets assume this is my model instance:

```
<xforms:instance id="main">
    <form>
        <section-1/>
        <section-2/>
        <rep-section>
            <a/>
            <b/>
            <c/>
        </rep-section>
    </form>
</xforms:instance>
```

I have a scenario where in i have an repeatable section `<rep-section>` which can be dynamically added in the form by an 'Add' button in form. There is another button only on first section 'Copy to other sections' which on click should copy the entire contents in the first section to the rest of the sections. Say if i have 7 sections, then the first section contents should be copied to the remaining 6 sections.

Please advise how we can achieve this.

I have an idea which works fine, but i think there should be an optimized way to do this.

```
<xforms:trigger appearance="minimal">
    <xforms:label>Copy to other Sections</xforms:label>
    <xforms:action ev:event="DOMActivate">???</xforms:action>
</xforms:trigger>
```

Comment: And when you click the button "Copy to other sections", do you want the content of the other sections to be removed, i.e. replaced with the content of the first section? Are the other sections named `<section-2>`, `<section-3>`, `<section-4>`, and so on?

Comment: Hi, when i have 4 repeated sections then there will be 4 <rep-section> nodes. When i click on button, i dont mind abt the data for sections in 2,3 and 4. We can delete 2,3,4 or just replace the node value inside them with first section. but i want to know an optimised approach because my form allows user to add upto 100 additional sections. So performance wise im lookng for an optimised approach. Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following will do it:

```
<xforms:trigger>
    <xforms:label>Copy to other section</xforms:label>
    <xforms:action ev:event="DOMActivate">
        <xxforms:variable name="source" select="."/>
        <xforms:action ev:event="DOMActivate" xxforms:iterate="../* except .">
            <xforms:delete ref="*"/>
            <xforms:insert context="." origin="$source/*"/>
        </xforms:action>
    </xforms:action>
</xforms:trigger>
```

You can see in action in this [full example](https://gist.github.com/1685914).

Comment: I didnt try that 'expect' syntax in xpath expressions so far.. good to know. great answer. Thank you very much.

Comment: Good, I'm glad this helped. Alternatively, you could also use `preceding-sibling::* | following-sibling:*`, but it's a bit longer type. It would be nice to have a `sibling` axis which combines both the preceding and following siblings. https://twitter.com/#!/avernet/status/162904972319662080